# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Weapons'

Tags: python

I have my own python package, but python can't find it (pycharm venv)

my project structure

[image]

Also I can import it trough the Python console, but still importing in console doesn't works in the project.

[image]

Comment: Your import is wrong. It should be `from player import Weapons`, and it also depends on your working directory

Comment: @ThePyGuy, thank you so much! This solves many of my errors! :)